# Group object keys values in order to obtain a list of objects grouped by a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an object like:

```
{
"Account Management": [
    {
        "rowId": 1288,
        "departmentExternalId": "7",
        "departmentName": "Account Management",
        "measureName": "Total Headcount Expense",
        "measureId": 15,
        "measureValue": 17282,
    },
    {
        "rowId": 1289,
        "departmentExternalId": "7",
        "departmentName": "Account Management",
        "measureName": "Salary",
        "measureId": 5,
        "measureValue": 11666,
    },
],
"Client Services General (COR)": [
    {
        "rowId": 1294,
        "departmentExternalId": "114",
        "departmentName": "Client Services General (COR)",
        "measureName": "Total Headcount",
        "measureId": 2,
        "measureValue": 1,
    },
    {
        "rowId": 1295,
        "departmentExternalId": "114",
        "departmentName": "Client Services General (COR)",
        "measureName": "Total Headcount",
        "measureId": 2,
        "measureValue": 100,
    }
]
}
```

Each object key represents the **department**, object obtained after grouping the data got from BE. Now I need to group each object inside department by **measureId** and count them to obtain something like:

```
[
  {department: "Account Management", measure15: 17282, measure5: 11666},
  {department: "Client Services General (COR)", measure2: 101}
]
```

I tried to group the grouped by department data again by measureId, but I here I have a blocker and don't know how to continue.

If anybody has any idea, please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to group each department array by measureId and then reduce to obtain the expected result, but I’m doing wrong.

Comment: You've got this tagged as "TypeScript" but I don't see any TypeScript here; presumably to implement your algorithm, step one, for TypeScript, would be to write interfaces for the data structures you're dealing with.  Could you do that and post it to make a [mre]?  Otherwise you're asking others to do absolutely everything here, from scratch. Maybe that will happen, but you're more likely to get good responses if you don't require that.

Comment: I can define those interfaces later, for now I just need to know if it is possible

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Now can you define the interfaces for me?  I actually have written an algorithm that does what you want, sitting in a temporarily deleted answer to this question.  But I've got things like `interface Foo { rowId: number, departmentExternalId: string ... }` and `interface Bar { department: string, ... }` and `interface FooDict { [k: string]: Foo[] }`.  I don't like those names, do you?   Could you help make this a [mre] and I'll undelete the answer and explain it?

Comment: For me, those interfaces are ok. Even if an JS answer to my question will be ok. After that I will adapt

Comment: Oh well, I guess I can't help you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the function `Array.prototype.reduce` we can create an object with keys equal to the departmentNames, and then we can extract the objects as an array with the function `Object.values`.

Finally, by using the function `Array.prototype.flatMap` we can transform an array of arrays into a simple array.

```js
const obj = {  "Account Management": [{    rowId: 1288,    departmentExternalId: "7",    departmentName: "Account Management",    measureName: "Total Headcount Expense",    measureId: 15,    measureValue: 17282  }, {    rowId: 1289,    departmentExternalId: "7",    departmentName: "Account Management",    measureName: "Salary",    measureId: 5,    measureValue: 11666  }, ],  "Client Services General (COR)": [{    rowId: 1294,    departmentExternalId: "114",    departmentName: "Client Services General (COR)",    measureName: "Total Headcount",    measureId: 2,    measureValue: 1  }, {    rowId: 1295,    departmentExternalId: "114",    departmentName: "Client Services General (COR)",    measureName: "Total Headcount",    measureId: 2,    measureValue: 100  }]},
      output = Object.values(obj).flatMap((array) => {
        return Object.values(array.reduce((a, d) => {
          const currentMeasure = a[d.departmentName]?.[`measure${d.measureId}`];

          a[d.departmentName] = {...(a[d.departmentName] || {department: d.departmentName}), [`measure${d.measureId}`]: (currentMeasure || 0) + d.measureValue};
          return a;
        }, {}));
      });

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is to create an array of objects that store the

```
[{measureX: sumOfValuesX}, {measureY: sumOfValuesY, ...}]
```

For each specific id of the corresponding department. Then, by destructuring the object and combining it with `Object.assign()`, you can flat that whole array and have all values available.

As seen in this approach with additional use of `Object.entries()` and `reduce()`:

```js
let obj={"Account Management":[{rowId:1288,departmentExternalId:"7",departmentName:"Account Management",measureName:"Total Headcount Expense",measureId:15,measureValue:17282},{rowId:1289,departmentExternalId:"7",departmentName:"Account Management",measureName:"Salary",measureId:5,measureValue:11666},],"Client Services General (COR)":[{rowId:1294,departmentExternalId:"114",departmentName:"Client Services General (COR)",measureName:"Total Headcount",measureId:2,measureValue:1},{rowId:1295,departmentExternalId:"114",departmentName:"Client Services General (COR)",measureName:"Total Headcount",measureId:2,measureValue:100}]}

output = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({
    "department": key,
    ...Object.assign(...value.reduce((acc, {measureId, measureValue} ) => {
       let measureIdKey = `measure${measureId}`
       let currId = acc.filter(x => x[measureIdKey])
       return (currId.length ?
            (currId[0][measureIdKey] += measureValue
                , acc) : [...acc, { [measureIdKey]: measureValue }])
    }, [])) 
}))

console.log(output)
```

In Typescript, it has some modifications to follow the typing stuff.

```
type Info = {
    measureValue: string;
    measureId: number;
}

type Foo = { [key: string]: string | number; } 

type Department = {
    rowId: number;
    departmentExternalId: string;
    departmentName: string;
    measureName: string;
    measureValue: number;
} | Info


let output = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({
    "department": key,
    ...applyReduce(value as Info[])
})) 
 
function applyReduce(foo: Info[]) {
    return foo.reduce((acc: Info[], { measureValue, measureId }: Info): any => {
        let measureIdKey = `measure${measureId}`

        let currId: Foo[] = []  // this line is needed to compile
        acc.forEach(x => currId.push(x)) // this line too

        currId = currId.filter(x => x[measureIdKey])
        return (currId.length ?
            (currId[0][measureIdKey] += measureValue
                , acc) : [...acc, { [measureIdKey]: measureValue }])
    }, []).reduce((a, c) => ({...a,...c}), {})  // added another reduce
} 

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I get an error on (...value.reduce) telling that: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it @testing_22 ?

Comment: Typescript is not my strongest, but I made it work. Check the edit, please.